# Connecting to ubuntu box at home from work

Tags: display, display-resolution, remote-desktop

I have a setup with a Windows 10 laptop at work and a desktop computer at home with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I would like to access my home desktop (box) from work preferably with a GUI.

I've installed TeamViewer 13 on both machines and can connect fine to the box. My issue is however, that I plugged in my TV as a monitor to the box in order to check the connection. Now when I unplug the monitor, the display settings are still active in the box, such that the resolution on my laptop is terrible. I can't change the display settings to match the monitor I have at work, and the connection is seriously slow (I suspect because of the high resolution on the box side).

Is there a fix for this situation? Should I use another, easier solution than TeamViewer?

Answer (score 0):

In teamviewer you have at the top of the screen the menu point 'View' containing a dropdown menu to configure the partner's screen resolution.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that. When the monitor on the box is not plugged in, the screen resolution button is greyed out.